# Matrix A.S Goes to Zero

Tags: linear-algebra, probability, statistics

Let
$$Y_{i}\overset{\text{i.i.d}}\sim N(0, I_p).$$

If we let $$\bar{Y}=\sum_{i=1}^{n}Y_i \text{ and } \bar{Y}_i=\frac{1}{m(n)}\sum_{j=1}^{m(n)}Y_{i\ell + j},$$

where $\ell$ is just a parameter and $m(n)$ is a function that grows with n. I am trying to show that $\bar{Y}_i\bar{Y}^T$ goes to zero almost surely or at least in probability. This is what I was considering. Let $||\cdot ||_2$ be the Euclidean norm. The following holds my Markov's Inequality

$$\mathbb{P}\left(\left|\left|\bar{Y}_i\bar{Y}^T\right|\right|_2^2\ge \epsilon\right)\le \frac{E\left|\left|\bar{Y}_i\bar{Y}^T\right|\right|_2^2}{\epsilon}.$$

Since $$\left|\left|\bar{Y}_i\bar{Y}^T\right|\right|_2^2\le\text{trace}\left(\bar{Y}\bar{Y}_i^T\bar{Y}_i\bar{Y}^T\right)=\left|\left|\bar{Y}_i\right|\right|_2^2\left|\left|\bar{Y}\right|\right|_2^2.$$

This follows, I believe because $\bar{Y}\bar{Y}_i^T\bar{Y}_i\bar{Y}^T$ is positive semi definite and the trace property of products. Then

$$\mathbb{P}\left(\left|\left|\bar{Y}_i\bar{Y}^T\right|\right|_2^2\ge \epsilon\right)\le \frac{E\left|\left|\bar{Y}_i\right|\right|_2^2\left|\left|\bar{Y}\right|\right|_2^2}{\epsilon}.$$

Now I will need to bound $\bar{Y}$. Let $S_n(i)=\sum_{j=1}^{n}y_{ij}$, then

$$\bar{Y} =\frac{1}{n}\begin{bmatrix}S_n(1)\\S_n(2)\\ \vdots \\S_n(p)\end{bmatrix}.$$

Then

$$\left|\left|\bar{Y}\right|\right|_2^2=\frac{1}{n^2}\sum_{j=1}^{p}S_j^2.$$

By the law of iterated algorithm for  a given $\epsilon>0$ there exists a large enough n  s.t.

$$|S_n(i)|\le (1+\epsilon)\sqrt{2n\log\log n},$$

implying,

$$S_n(i)^2\le (1+\epsilon)^22n\log\log n,$$

resulting in
$$\left|\left|\bar{Y}\right|\right|_2^2\le (1+\epsilon)^2 \frac{2p\log\log n}{n}.$$

Finally,

$$E\left|\left|\bar{Y}_i\right|\right|_2^2=\bar{Y}_i^T\bar{Y}_i=\frac{1}{m(n)^2}\sum_{j=1}^{m(n)}EY_{i\ell +j}^TY_{i\ell +j}
 + \frac{2}{m(n)^2}\sum_{j=1}^{m_n}\sum_{k>j}^{m_n}EY_{i\ell +j}^TY_{i\ell +k}=\frac{p}{m(n)}.$$

Combining everything, for large enough n,

$$\mathbb{P}\left(\left|\left|\bar{Y}_i\bar{Y}^T\right|\right|_2^2\ge \epsilon\right)\le\frac{E\left|\left|\bar{Y}_i\right|\right|_2^2\left|\left|\bar{Y}\right|\right|_2^2}{\epsilon}\le \frac{(1+\epsilon)^2}{\epsilon} \frac{2p\log\log n}{n}E\left|\left|\bar{Y}_i\right|\right|_2=\frac{(1+\epsilon)^2}{\epsilon} \frac{2p^2\log\log n}{nm(n)}.$$

I figure in the Euclidean induced  matrix norm,

$$\left|\left|\bar{Y}_i\bar{Y}^T\right|\right|_2^2 \overset{p}{\rightarrow} 0 \text{ if }\frac{\log\log n}{nm(n)}\rightarrow 0,$$

and

$$\left|\left|\bar{Y}_i\bar{Y}^T\right|\right|_2^2 \overset{a.s.}{\rightarrow} 0 \text{ if }\sum\frac{\log\log n}{nm(n)}<\infty.$$

If this holds, either in probability or a.s, then,$\lambda_{\text{max}}$ being the largest eigenvalue, $$\lambda_{\text{max}}\left(\bar{Y}\bar{Y}_i^T\bar{Y}_i\bar{Y}^T\right)\rightarrow 0.$$

Since $$\bar{Y}\bar{Y}_i^T\bar{Y}_i\bar{Y}^T\ge 0,$$, then $$\lambda\left(\bar{Y}\bar{Y}_i^T\bar{Y}_i\bar{Y}^T\right)\rightarrow 0,$$

implying

$$\bar{Y}\bar{Y}_i^T\bar{Y}_i\bar{Y}^T\rightarrow 0_p,$$
implying

$$\bar{Y}_i\bar{Y}^T\rightarrow 0_p.$$

Does my logic follow or are there some areas I need to pay attention to?